# Serial to USB Cable (CH340) - New Driver Not Functioning with C# Application - "A device attached to the system is not functioning"

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a C# application that connects to a device through a Serial to USB Cable. The cable model is CH340. The problem is that in various clients, it stopped working overnight. Upon checking the driver, a new version was automatically installed on February 11, 2023.

[image]

The command to connect is as follows:

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, baudRate, parity, dataBits, stopBits);
_serialPort.Open();
```

However, after executing _serialPort.Open(), an exception is thrown with the following error message:

```
"a device attached to the system is not functioning"
```

Going back to an older version of the driver resolves the issue.

Has anyone used the same cable and successfully connected it to C# after updating the driver?

Answer (score 2):

I've got the very same issue with the new version 3.8 driver. My application has stopped working with CH340G chip on Mega 2560 Pro board. Arduino IDE can't connect to this board with the new driver as well. If I install the previous driver version 3.7 everything works fine.

Comment: The problem we have is that Windows is automatically updating the driver for our customers. I tried to contact the manufacturer, but they are a company in China and they ignored my emails... This is a serious issue that affects the functionality of the CH340 cables. Is there no other solution besides manually reverting to the old driver?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, and tried to fix it by installing some version of driver

My new laptop runs Windows 11 and the lastest driver version is 2023. My old laptop runs Windows 10 and the latest version is 2019. 2019 version is fine and 2023 version got that issue. May be some incompatible points between C# library and new driver.

I tried to install some versions of driver and chose the old one (2019 or 2014). My C# application back to work and the windows don't force me to update and use new version 2023 anymore.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijIyx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

**Info provided by Henry Kafeman**
Henry.Kafeman@hdksolutions.co.uk

We have encountered the same issue using an RS232 to USB cable with the CH340 chip.

Our code is written in VBA for Excel using Kernel32 routines and has been running okay for several years for multiple customers with Windows 10 and Windows 11 using WCH CH341SER Driver versions up to 3.7.2022.01.

But the latest Driver version 3.8.2023.2 is now just causing errors as posted in this question. These are from the ClearCommError() and GetCommState() Kernel32 routines.

The following are some more details to assist others.

Unfortunately the Driver version is now automatically updated by Windows as it is included in the "Microsoft Update Catalog" website (https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com) and it seems for W11 (22H2 and later) that the CH340 Driver was updated to version 3.8.2023.2 on 10th February 2023, superseding version 3.5.2019.1 (which was updated on 29th January 2019) for Windows 10.

You can stop all Windows 11 Automatic Driver Updates as follows, but this does not seem to actually prevent the CH341SER Driver from being updated, perhaps because it is in the "Microsoft Update Catalog"?:

### ***Turn Off Windows 11 Automatic Driver Updates from Control Panel***

- Click **Start** menu, type **change device installation settings**, click
  Change device installation settings in the search results to open the
  Device installation settings window.
- Select the **No (your device might    not work as expected)** option and
  click the **Save Changes** button. This    will stop Windows 11 from
  automatically updating drivers

  *To enable automatic driver updates in Windows 11 again, you can access the Device installation settings window again and select the **Yes (recommended) option.***

Also, it is obviously not ideal to disable all Driver Updates, which might have security and stability issues for other device Drivers. Or, at least mean that IT Support and time is needed to periodically install them and then roll back the CH341SER driver to a known working version!

### Disable the specific Driver update

Another workaround I have found is to disable the specific Driver update which can be done as follows (though I think major Windows updates may still re-enable these?):

- As per https://windowsreport.com/enable-gpedit-msc/ from a CMD prompt
  "Run as administrator" run these commands to install the Group Policy
  Editor if it is not available:

  ```
     pushd "%~dp0"
     dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientExtensions-Package~3*.mum >List.txt
     dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~3*.mum >>List.txt
     for /f %%i in ('findstr /i . List.txt 2^>nul') do dism /online /norestart /add-package:"%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\%%i"
     pause
  ```
- As per
  https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/146562-prevent-windows-update-updating-specific-device-driver.html
  disable the specific Driver for the CH340 device:

  Please take all necessary precautions and heed warnings about the potential risks of editing the Registry.

  In our case we needed to do add the following, though the VID, PID and REV values could vary with different devices, etc.:

  ```
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions]
   "DenyDeviceIDs"=dword:00000001
   "DenyDeviceIDsRetroactive"=dword:00000001

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions\DenyDeviceIDs]
   "1"="USB\\VID_1A86&PID_7523&REV_0254"
   "2"="USB\\VID_1A86&PID_7523"
  ```

  The VID, PID and REV values can be found in Device Manager "Hardware Ids" or in the registry as Hex values for "HardwareID" in this branch:

  ```
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_1A86&PID_7523\[Id string]
  ```

  Where **[Id string]** is e.g. "5&242a2f40&0&1", "6&956e9b8&0&4", etc.:

  ```
     "DeviceDesc"="@oem46.inf,%ch340ser.devicedesc%;USB-SERIAL CH340"
     "FriendlyName"="USB-SERIAL CH340 (COMxx)"
  ```

  Once the Registry "...DeviceInstall\Restrictions" values above have been added, then  run the following command in a CMD prompt "Run as administrator" to action the changes:

  ```
     gpupdate /force
  ```

---

The WCH.cn web page specifically lists these Chip variants as being supported (W10 and W11) by version 3.8.2023, though their update date is 16th March versus the 10th February for the "Windows Update Catalog":

```
CH340G, CH340T, CH340C, CH340N, CH340K, CH340E, CH340B
CH341A, CH341F, CH341T, CH341B, CH341C, CH341U
```

I have not been able to find out from our cable supplier which CH340 variant they use despite them having asked the actual manufacturer.

I have exchanged several Emails with WCH Technical Support and they have told me that a new Evaluation Board for the CH340, will be available from their online store in the next week.

Then if test with their Evaluation Board, which has a known good CH340 chip, and still experiences the issue with the latest Driver they have said:

*"I have spoken to my colleagues on the Driver side about your problem, and after using our EVT and still having the same problem, they will actively cooperate to find the problem."*

I will post updates in due course....

**Update Jan-24-2024**
The official WCH store is here: https://wchofficialstore.aliexpress.com/store/1100367542

They now have Evaluation Board (EVT) products for both the CH340 and CH341 chips available.

We (as well as the original questioner Cezar Wagenheimer) have ordered the CH340C9R-EVT-RS232 product so that we can test it with our systems to inform the WCH when/if the issue persists with their latest driver version.

Delivery to us is however, not due until 9th February 2024.

We will update this thread in due course.

***Update Jan-02-2024***
WCH.cn said:

"I asked a colleague on the driver side and the latest driver for the CH340 is fully compatible with WIN10 and WIN11."

"The reason for this problem is still caused by using a chip that is not original."

On testing we found that the CH340C9R-EVT-RS232 does work okay for our application (running on Windows 11) with both v3.8.2023.2 and v3.7.2022.01!

We are looking to get 3D Printed cases made so that we can supply to our customers in place of the cable we have been using.

***Update Feb-16-2024***
Henry Kafeman is using this cable :

"RS PRO RS232 USB A Male to DB-9 Male Converter Cable"
Brand: RS Pro

Find more details and purchase here: uk.rs-online.com/web/p/interface-adapters-converters/1445699

Who is experiencing the same issue, please share details about the cables you have used.

Your input will be valuable in understanding and resolving the matter. We appreciate the collaboration of everyone

***Update Mar-03-2024***
I recently acquired the CH340C9R-EVT-RS232 from AliExpress, and I'm pleased to report that it functions seamlessly with your application using the latest driver version on Windows 11.